# Codeschool Surviving Apis with Rails - Testing Routes for Header Versioning

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, unit-testing, rspec

For some reason this challenge feels completely borked. Here is the starter question for 5.9:

> New requirements have come in and we need to change our API to support
>   versioning through a custom Mime Type. This new Mime Type is going to
>   be called Apocalypse and will read from a specific request header.
>   Let’s start by writing some integration tests.

**Task 1**

> Set the proper request header used for versioning, with the value for
>   our new custom media type of application/vnd.zombies.v1+json.

**Task 2**

> Assert the Content-Type on the response is set to JSON.

**Task 3**

> Now parse the response body and assert that there is a message
>   property set to "This is version one". Check the test/test_helper.rb
>   file on the secondary tab for a helper method that can help save some
>   time.

Here is the setup `test/test_helper.rb`

```
ENV['RAILS_ENV'] = 'test'
require File.expand_path('../../config/environment', __FILE__)
require 'rails/test_help'

class ActiveSupport::TestCase
  ActiveRecord::Migration.check_pending!
  fixtures :all

  def json(body)
    JSON.parse(body, symbolize_names: true)
  end
end
```

Here is my current answer:

```
class ListingZombiesTest < ActionDispatch::IntegrationTest
  test 'show zombie from API version 1' do
    get '/zombies/1',{},{'Accept' => 'application/vnd.zombies.v1+json' }
    assert_equal 200, response.status
    assert_equal Mime::JSON, response.content_type
    assert_equal "This is version one", json(response.body)

  end
end
```

I get the error:

`Did not parse the response body`

Thoughts?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

FINALLY THIS WORKED!

```
class ListingZombiesTest < ActionDispatch::IntegrationTest
  test 'show zombie from API version 1' do
    get '/zombies/1',{},{'Accept' => 'application/vnd.zombies.v1+json' }
    assert_equal 200, response.status
    assert_equal Mime::JSON, response.content_type
    message = json(response.body)
        assert_equal "This is version one", message['message']
  end
end
```